# Dynamics AX Full Compile during business hours

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

We have a user who ran a full compile from the AOT during the day. What is the impact? So far nothing bad has happened. I know your not supposed the close the compile job window under any circumstances.

Comment: This is Dynamics AX 2012 R2

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the system was really, really slow for about 4 hours, but AX was still functional. There was one class with external dependencies that did not compile correctly, and we logged into each AOS and ran a restore and compile on that one class. We are going to run a full compile this weekend, but everything seems to be running fine now.